# Yii themes not working

Tags: php, yii, themes

I am a newbie and learning `yii` but facing this problem with themes. I followed [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming) url and copied all the contents of `/protected/views` into `/themes/classic/views` . Also added
    `'theme'=>array( 'classic',) ,` in `/config/main.php` file but `theme` is not getting activated. I receive the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getViewFile() on a non-object in E:\Projects\yii\framework\web\CController.php on line 587.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Faisal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistakenly set the theme to an array instead of a string. The correct configuration is

```
'theme' => 'classic',
```

Fixing this will take care of the error.